# Accessed the GCP VM SSH from local machine, but cannot view anything

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I have accessed GCP VM from my local machine by SSH key. When I tried to view documents in the VM just simply typing "ls", but nothing showed up as picture presents. There were supposed to have some folders. 
How can properly access the VM from my local machine?
[GCP VM view from local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgL3L.png)

Comment: Howdy ... welcome to Stackoverflow.   If one created a new Compute Engine instance and then logged in via SSH and then ran "ls" ... what you are seeing is exactly what I would expect to see ... an empty directory.  What makes you believe that there should be files already present in your home directory?

Comment: You might be using the wrong user name. Try `ls -l /home`

Comment: I have pulled a repository into the Compute Engine instance. I can list the directory when I access the Compute Engine instance from GCP. However, when accessing it from my laptop, nothing shows up while typing "ls".

Comment: I guess you are accessing it under different user name when logging from laptop. Try going to parent dir `cd ..` and check for GCP user folder in it.

Comment: Thank you! It is the user issue. It's solved now! appreciate it !